# Complement of a knot that *isn't* rationally null-homologous

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, 3d, knot-theory

Let $K$ be a knot in a closed, oriented 3-manifold $Y$. It is a standard fact that if $K$ is (at least rationally) null-homologous, then $H_1(Y-K;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to $H_1(Y;\mathbb{Z})\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. I'm curious about the case where $K$ is *not* rationally nullhomologous, i.e. when $[K]$ has infinite order in $H_1(Y)$.

> What is $H_1(Y-K)$ if $K$ is *not* rationally null-homologous?

To make a few initial observations, let $N(K)$ denote a tubular neighborhood of our knot $K$ (which is assumed to satisfy $[K]\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$-homology) and let $\mu$ be a meridian of $K$ in $\partial N(K)$. Then:

- by the "half lives, half dies" principle, $\mu$ must represent a trivial element in $H_1(Y-K;\mathbb{Q})$ and thus a finite-order element in $\mathbb{Z}$-homology;
- $Y$ is obtained from $Y- \mathring{N}(K)$ by attaching a 2-handle along $\mu$ (and capping off the remaining $S^2$-boundary with a 3-ball), so its first homology should be the quotient of $H_1(Y-K)$ by the subgroup generated by $\mu$.

Based on this, my guess is that $H_1(Y-K)\cong H_1(Y) \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n$ where $n$ is the order of $\mu$.

Comment: @PVAL: I've tinkered with the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for $Y=(Y-K) \cup N(K)$ quite a bit. You can pull out a short exact sequence $0 \to \operatorname{coker} \delta \to H_1(N(K)) \oplus H_1(Y-K) \to H_1(Y) \to 0$, which I think further reduces to $0 \to \langle \mu \rangle_{\partial N(K)}/\langle n \cdot \mu \rangle \to H_1(Y-K) \to H_1(Y) \to 0$. I'm stuck there.

Comment: @PVAL: As for your example, the complement of that knot is $S^1 \times (S^2 -\{p\})$, which has the same first homology as the original space.

Comment: Sorry, that was incorrect. I guess the question is can we rule out something like $0 \to \Bbb Z/2 \to \Bbb Z/4 \to \Bbb Z/2 \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

All your steps are correct, you actually get $H_1(Y-K)/(\mu) \cong H_1Y$. Now in fact $[\mu]=0$ in your case, cf. [Homology of knot exterior in general manifold for not null-homologus knot](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630512/homology-of-knot-exterior-in-general-manifold-for-not-null-homologus-knot)

In case you are missing any details let me know. (the only thing you basically use is Poincaré duality and some differential topology).