# Homology of knot exterior in general manifold for not null-homologus knot

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory

I was trying to figure out the homology of the knot complement when $K$ is not a rational null-homologous knot ($[K]\neq 0\in H_1(X_K,\mathbb Q)$).

We then know by half-lives half dies that the meridian class has to be a torsion element or zero in the complement. By using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence with the knot neighbourhood and the complement I get:

$$0\rightarrow \mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z[u]\oplus\mathbb Z[l]\rightarrow  H_1(X_K)\oplus\mathbb Z[l]\rightarrow  H_1(Y)\rightarrow 0$$

then I do not know how to keep going.

Comment: Is your manifold 3-dimensional? Otherwise I can't make sense out of the "half lives half dies" thingy...

Comment: There is a version of Alexander duality for any oriented closed n-manifold. Precisely, that $H^{q}(X)$ is isomorphic to $H_{n-q}(M,M \setminus X)$. (See theorem 4.92 [here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/notes/homology.pdf).) That's probably useful.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously $[K]\neq 0$ in the complement. Hence the image in Mayer Vietoris identifies this element $[K]$ with $l$ to obtain $H_1Y$ (to compute the latter is our goal for now).

As you mentioned correctly, the meridian has to be (possibly trivial) torsion in $H_1X_K$. Anyway we obtain $H_1Y$ as the quotient $H_1X_K \oplus \mathbb Z / (([K],1),([M],0)) \cong H_1X_K$, where the last isomorphism holds iff $[M]=0$.

To show that this is in fact always true (at least in the orientable case), and hence our result is $H_1X_K\cong H_1Y$, note that by Poincaré duality we can find an orientable surface $S$ in $Y$ intersecting transversely $K$ precisely once. Now $X_K\cap S$ gives us a nullbordism.

(or in fancier words: in the exact Mayer Vietoris sequence above the meridian is in the image of $H_2Y$ and hence maps to zero by exactness)

Comment: We get such a surface also in the non-orientable case, similarly as in the orientable case (pick one with odd intersection number, then surger),

Comment: If $[K]$ is not primitive, must it still intersect such a surface once?  For example, take $K$ to be a simple closed curve in $S^1 \times S^2$ winding twice around the $S^1$ factor. Since $H_2(S^1 \times S^2 ;\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $\{pt\} \times S^2$, it seems like $K$ cannot intersect an embedded orientable surface transversely in a single point.

Comment: @Kyle In fact for the intersection pairing on $H_1 \times H_2$ mod torsion we have $\langle [K], [\{pt\} \times S^2] \rangle =\pm 2$ (depending on how you orient these things) so you are correct that there cannot be a closed orientable surface which intersects it exactly once transversely.

Comment: @PVAL and Kyle: Yes thanks for pointing that out. Of course I assumed $[K]$ to be primitive, otherwise we usually run into problems.